# How to create a deeply nested python dictionary using the following csv under specific rules

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, recursion, tree

I am creating a multi-level nested dictionary by reading from a large CSV file. The content the files are in the following format, which stores relevant information pertaining to a unique book. We can assume each row has 6 columns(author, title, year, category, URL, citations); all column entries have identical formatting. For example:

```
Author,Title,Year,Category,Url,Citations
"jk rowling, etc....",goblet of fire,1973,magic: fantasy: english literature,http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808066,6
"Weiner, Leonard H.",cracking the coding interview,1973,LA: assessment: other,http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808105,2
"Tolkien",hobbit,1953,magic: fantasy: medieval,http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808066,6
```

I want the output to match how each row in the CSV file is parsed, similar to the following:
*(note: the # of nested dictionaries is dependent on the book categories under the category header of the csv. first. keys at depth 1 aka the first sublayer are ordered by year the books were implemented. Keys at depth 2 and beyond up to the leaves, further extend the ordering from the 1st sublayer but now furthermore based on successive categories (order matters), separated by the ':' delimiter. Think of the ordering of categories per row in the CSV file as the path directory; multiple files can have the same path directory up to a certain point or they can have the same path directory and be placed in the same folder.

```
results = {'1973':{
    "magic": {
        "fantasy": {
            "English literature": {
                "name": "goblet of fire",
                "citations": 6,
                "url": "http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808066"
            }
        },},
        "medieval": {
            "name": "The Hobbit",
            "citations": 7,
            "url": "http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800fdfdffd010.808066"
        }
    },
    {'1953': "la": {
        "assessment": {
            "other": {
                "name": "cracking the coding interview",
                "citations": 6,
                "url": "http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808105"
            }
        }
      }

    }
}
```

Obviously, some books will have share common successive categories OR common publication dates together like in the example I showed above. Some books might also share the exact same successive categories. I think I should recursively iterate through the string of categories per row in the csv, either creating new sub dicts that deviate from a preexisting category order, then creating a dictionary representation of the book once there are no more successive categories to check. I'm just not sure exactly how to start.

Here's what I have so far, it's just a standard setup of reading CSV files:

```
  _, *data = csv.reader(open(DATA_FILE))
    new_data = [[i[3].split(': '), *i[4:], *i[:3]] for i in data]
    print(json.dumps(group(new_data), indent=4))
    return group(new_data)

def group(d):
    _d = {}
    for a, *b in d:
        if a[0] not in _d:
            _d[a[0]] = [[a[1:], *b]]
        else:
            _d[a[0]].append([a[1:], *b])
    r = {a: {'books': [
        {'name': c[-2],'year':c[-1], 'citations': c[2], 'url': c[1], 'author': c[3]} for
        c in b if not c[0]], **(lambda x: {} if not x else group(x))(
        [c for c in b if c[0]])} for a, b in _d.items()}
    return {a: {c: d for c, d in b.items() if d} for a, b in r.items()}
```

*Essentially, I want to create a tree representation of this csv using nested dictionaries, first level ordered by publication date, following levels further extend on this and further order books based on the relative category path (i.e. magic:fantasy: etc...), determining which subtree to traverse/create. If two or more books have the same consecutive path, I want to make all those books leaf of their respective key, instead of overriding each book(leaf) whenever a new book has an identical category path. Leaves represent a dictionary representation of the books mentioned per row in the csv.*

EDIT:
I can't use any dependencies/external modules

Comment: What's the error|problem?

Comment: I would recommend to use pandas for that matter. 'read_csv' and 'groupby' should do the trick.

Comment: can't use any dependencies/external modules

Comment: @Alderven rn i have it so it creates a nested dict based on the categories but now i want to create a nest dictionary based on publication date, then categories.